# MAC address transmitted using RouterOS?

Tags: mac-address

Using routerOS connected to another Access Point what MAC address will be sent to the remote AP ?
The MAC address of the mikrotik router or of the device connected to this router ?

Comment: Which client mode are you using? What protocol are you using (802.11, NV2 etc)?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] for a personal network.

Answer (score 1):

It depend on the router configuration :

- if the router configured to bridge the traffic between the router client interface and the AP interface the AP will receive the whole clients MAC address
- but if the router configured as normal L3 router which is the most case , the AP will see the router interface MAC address where it is connected